# How to fetch data from database to dropdown menu without submitting the form depending on the previous dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a html page with 4 dropdown menus. I would like to load 2nd dropdown menu to automatically load with database data without submitting the form. Heres my code

```
<?php
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost     Database=inventory;",'sa','123456');
?>

<html>
<body>

<fieldset>
<legend><b>Inventory Entry</b></legend>
<form method="post" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Item:</td>
<td>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT name from item";
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
?>

<select name="item">
<option value=""></option>
<?php while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['item']; ?>"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
</td>
<td>Sub Item Code:</td>
<td>
<select name="sub_item_code">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Brand:</td>
<td>
<select name="brand">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</td>
<td>Model:</td>
<td>
<select name="model">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

after selecting 1st drop down menu(i.e. computer server) the 2nd dropdown will generate from database(i.e. tower server, pc server,....). same will go on for 3rd & 4th dropdown according to their selection. My database has 4 columns (item, sub_item_code, brand, model). any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: I'm didn't used ajax before. if you kindly give a demo corresponding to this code, it will be really helpful...

Comment: creating whole demo will be time taking, i might post it here but now i am kind of busy in some other stuff, this flow might help you. Study events in jquery, on change event create JQuery's ajax request and let the server respond(you'll have to write server code too) with new list options, using ajax request's callback update your UI. thats it

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try to study those, if possible please post demo whenever u get time.